# Empty text space in a continuous Text component react-native

Tags: react-native

I have this problem:

[image]

I need to put the word "dummy" in the first line until the line was complete.

> You can see the sample here: https://snack.expo.io/B1KcRgGWX

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.paragraphs}>
          <Text style={styles.textParagraph}>Lorem Ipsum is</Text>
          <Text style={styles.emptyTerm} />
          <Text style={styles.textParagraph}>dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 25,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
    emptyTerm: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    minWidth: "25%"
  },
    paragraphs: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to wrap all your `<Text>` components with a `<Text>`!

So we have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text>Lorem Ipsum is </Text>
          <Text>{'     '}</Text>
          <Text>
            dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
            an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
            type specimen book
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 25,
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  }
});
```

but the problem is you can't set the `borderBottomWidth` to your **empty** `<Text>`!

---

## Solutions

1. Nesting a `<View>` in the middle of your `<Text>`.

So we have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text>Lorem Ipsum is </Text>
          <View style={styles.nestedViewStyle}>
            <Text>{'     '}</Text>
          </View>
          <Text>
            dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
            an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
            type specimen book
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 25,
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },

  nestedViewStyle: {
    width: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 5
  }
});
```

but **Nested Views** is iOS only ([Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.49/text.html#nested-views-ios-only))!

2. For android, it's some dirty coding but seems to work!

So we have something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text>Lorem Ipsum is </Text>
          <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>
            {'            '}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            {' '}
            dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
            an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
            type specimen book
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 25,
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  }
});
```

It's the way I think we can do it! If anybody has a better solution, I would appreciate writing an answer for this!

**UPDATE**

I've just created an [issue for this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19757) in the react-native repo!

### Update again!

You can use this function:

```js
splitPhrase = (phrase, isTerm = false) => {
  let words = phrase.split(' ');
  return words.map((i, k) => {
    return (
      <Text key={k} style={isTerm ? styles.emptyTerm : styles.paragraphs}>
        {' '}
        {i}{' '}
      </Text>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: It is really a dirty solution, but works for me now, unfortunally I dont´t see nothing better to solve this problem.

Comment: Yep! I've opened that issue! Would be great if you +1 there

Comment: I have a problem with your solution: The subComponent <Text> not trigger the proprety onLayout when it is inside another <Text> and I need it. :'(

Comment: I needed trigger the event onLayout, so use a SubText itsn't a option. I solve this with this function: ```splitPhrase = (phrase, isTerm = false) => {
    let words = phrase.split(" ");
    return words.map((i, k) => {
      return (
        <Text key={k} style={isTerm ? styles.textTerm : styles.textParagraph}>
          {i}
        </Text>
      );
    });
  };```

Comment: Printing Texts separated!

Comment: I will add this to my answer for further reference. Glad it's solved!