# Nested Text component containing whitespace is not displayed when positioned at the end of a line

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, text

I'm trying to have a placeholder made of whitespace inside a text. It works fine when the placeholder is at the beginning of a line or in the middle, but it is not rendered at all when positioned at the end of a line.

```
<Container>
  <View>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
        This TEXT is the first part of the sentence
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>{'   '}</Text>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        This is the second part
      </Text>
    </Text>
  </View>
</Container >
```

**Normal behaviour:**

[image]

**Strange behaviour:**

[image]

Context:

- running on Android
- versions: "react": "16.8.3", "react-native": "0.59.8",

Edit: Solved my problem by replacing the normal space characters with "\u00a0" characters, aka 'non-breaking space'

Answer (score 1):

So looking at other answers, it looks like the fix is a bit dirty [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884639/empty-text-space-in-a-continuous-text-component-react-native)

So here's what I did:

```js
        <View>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>
            <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
              This TEXT is the first part of the sentence
            </Text>
         </Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', fontSize: 18 }}>{'   '}</Text>
              <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', fontSize: 18 }}>
                This is the second part
              </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
```

and here's a [snack example](https://snack.expo.io/ry13eVZJr)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I solved my problem by replacing the normal space characters with "\u00a0" characters, aka 'non-breaking space'